# Resources consumed by a simple SELECT query in MySql

Tags: mysql, select, jdbc

There a few large tables in one of the databases of a customer (each table is ~50M rows in size and is not too wide). The intent is to infrequently read these tables (completely). As there are no reasonable CDC indices present, the plan is to read the tables by querying them

`SELECT * from large_table;`

The reads will be performed using a jdbc driver. With the following fetch configuration present, the intent is to read the data approximately one record at a time (it may require a significant amount of time) so that the client code is never overwhelmed.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(queryString, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

I was going through the [execution path of a query](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9781449332471/ch06.html#execution_path_of_a_query) in *High Performance MySQL*, however some questions seemed unanswered:

1. Without the temp tables being explicitly created and the query cache being made use of, "how" are the stream reads tracked on the server?
2. Is any *temporary* data created (in main memory or files on disk) whatsoever? If so, where is it created and how much?
3. If temporary data is not created, how are the rows to be returned tracked? Does the query engine keep track of all the page files to be read for this query on this connection? In case there are several such queries running on the server, are the earliest "Tracked" files purged in favor of queries submitted recently?

<sub>PS: I want to understand the effect of this approach on the MySql server (not saying that there aren't better ways of reading the tables)</sub>

Comment: Did you check mysql show processlist while connection.prepareStatement is executed?

Comment: Yes, the process list shows the query to be running as long as the connection is open

Comment: It is (somewhere) in the [MySQL Internals Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/)

Comment: I think you may get better answers at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*That* simple query will *not* use a temp table.  It will simply fetch the rows and transfer them to the client until it finishes.  Nor would any possible index be useful.  (If the real query is more complex, let's see it.)

The client may wait for all the rows (faster, but memory intensive) before it hands any to the user code, or it may hand them off one at a time (much slower).

I don't know the details in JDBC on specifying it.

You *may* want to page through the table.  If so, don't use `OFFSET`, but use the `PRIMARY KEY` and "remember where you left off".  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Your Question #3 leads to a complex answer...

*Every* query brings all the relevant data (and index entries) into RAM.  The data/index is read in chunks ("blocks") of 16KB from the BTree structure that is persisted on disk.  For a simple select like that, it will read the blocks 'sequentially' until finished.

But, be aware of "caching":

- If a block is already in RAM, no I/O is needed.
- If a block is not in the cache ("buffer_pool"), it will, if necessary, bump some block out and read the desired block in.  This is very normal, and very common.  Do not fear it.

Because of the simplicity of the query, only a few blocks ever need to be in RAM at any moment.  Hence, if your buffer pool were only a few megabytes, it could still handle, say, a 1TB table.  There would be a lot of I/O, and *that* would impact other operations.

As for "tracking", let me use the analogy of reading a long book *in a single sitting*.  There is nothing to track, you are simply turning pages ('blocks').  You don't even need a 'bookmark' for tracking, it is next-next-next...

Another note:  InnoDB uses "B+Tree", which includes a link from one block to the "next", thereby making the page turning efficient.

Another interpretation of tracking...  "Transactions" and "ACID".  When any query (read or write) touches a table, there is some form of lock applied to each row touched.  For `SELECT` the lock is rather light-weight.  For writes it can cause delays or even a "deadlock".  The locks are unavoidable, but sometimes actions can be taken to minimize their impact.

Logically (but not actually), a "snapshot" of all rows in all tables is taken at the instant you start a transaction.  This allows you to see a consistent view of everything, even if other connections are changing rows.  The underlying mechanism is very lightweight on reading, but heavier for writes.  Writes will make a copy of the row so that each connection sees the snapshot that it 'should' see.  Also, the copy allows for `ROLLBACK` and recovery from a crash (eg power failure).

(Transaction "isolation" mode allows some control over the snapshot.)  To get the optimal performance for your case, do nothing special.

Here's a way to conceptualize the handling of transactions:  Each row has a timestamp associated with it.  Each query saves the start time of the query.  The query can "see" only rows that are older than that start time.  A subsequent write in another connection will be creating *copies* of rows with a later timestamp, hence not visible to the `SELECT`.  Hence, the onus is on writes to do extra work; reads are cheap.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I felt that there is some sort of "tracking" because of this: While I was still reading on one connection (one row at a time), I added more rows to the table (on a different connection and committed them). However, these "new rows" were NOT read via the first connection - which part of the server is responsible to track this information?

Comment: @TJ- - Oh.  I added a few more paragraphs to address that meaning of "tracking".

Comment: This helped. I think you may be referring to the Repeatable Read isolation level (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html). Thank you!

Comment: @TJ- - I just leave the default for `innodb_tx_isolation`.